# Image not be picked in iOS simulator MacBook Pro m1

Tags: flutter, apple-m1

hello every I have been working on my app with flutter language and one of the operation that the app do is allowing the user to use a camera to take a photo then I save this photo to the firebase . the problem is when I press on the button on the simulator to take a picture the app is crashed then this error appears to me in terminal (Lost connection to device.)  and then a report is sending to apple from the device it self.

have you faced this problem ? please help me

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you add these permissions
`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`, and `NSCameraUsageDescription` to info.plist

Comment: I don't know where I can found the info.plist could you help me please my processor is M1

Comment: It is in your flutter project -> ios ->Runner -> Info.plist

Comment: You need to search how to add permission in infoplist file.

Comment: can I add those permissions in VS code on the file info.plist?